# How to hide UITableViewCellSelection after pressed?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that in my cellForRowsAtIndexPath, I have this:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
```

However, after the action occurs in my UINavigationController and I go back, it's still selected. Also, I have a UIAlertView that pops up for one of my actions. How can I hide it after the user has finished tapping it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the delegate method like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
[yourTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[yourTableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];
```